# How to read the contents of a CSV file and put it into a 2D array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I just want to ask on how to read the contents of a CSV file and put it into a 2D array.

The content of my CSV file contains 7 columns(which are comma separated ",") for each row. The rows on the other hand are separated by a dash/hyphen "-". But note that the rows are still on the same line(they are just identified when there is a dash/hyphen which separates the 7 columns(for each row).

(The contents that appear on the CSV file are user inputted, meaning the user inputs 7 values for columns in each row.)

[image: CSV File Content]

My problem is that whenever the user finishes inputting the values for the first row, I get a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7  which comes from the declared 7 columns of my 2D array(where I plan to insert the values of the CSV file) that is in my readCustomerCSV fuction.

The specific line from the function is this:  read2DString[read2DStringIndex][g] = fromfile[g];

Here is my source code:

```java
public void writeCustomerCSV() {  // everything in this snippet code works fine(it creates a CSV file which stores the inputs of the user)
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\RALPH\\Documents\\Database Java CSV\\customers.csv"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int y;
        for (int x = 0; x < itemTo2D.length; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < itemTo2D[0].length; y++) {
                if (itemTo2D[x] != null) {
                    sb.append(itemTo2D[x][y]);
                    sb.append(",");
                }
            }
            sb.append("-");  //separation for rows
            sb.append(",");  // separation for columns
        }
        bw.write(sb.toString());
        bw.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}

public void readCustomerCSV() {  // reads the contents of the CSV file     *having issues with ArrayINdexOutofBounds
    String[] fromfile = {};   // 1d string for getting the columns(7 columns) of the CSV file
    String[][] read2DString = new String[10][7];   // 2D array where the contents of the CSV file will be inserted (can only get 10 unique values of 7 columns)
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\RALPH\\Documents\\Database Java CSV\\customers.csv"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            fromfile = line.split(",");  //separates the columns by a comma
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

    for (int g = 0; g < fromfile.length; g++) {
        read2DString[read2DStringIndex][g] = fromfile[g];  // the ArrayIndexOutofBounds is here (inserts the values of the 2D array(by row))
        //   System.out.print(fromfile[g] + " ");
        if (fromfile[g].equals("-")) {     //if there is a presence of a dash, it increments the read2DStringINdex (row index) of the 2D array
            read2DStringIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything that I missed in my codes or is my approach not good enough?

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like the dash that represents a new line, at the 7th index (8th item in list) will trigger an out of bounds exception when adding to the read2DString (g would equal 7, which is out of bounds because the list would require an 8th column). I assume the solution would be to put the the if statement first and then break out of that iteration using a continue statement before you add it to the array to bypass the problem.

Comment: Basically, your program treats the "-" as an 8th column before going to the next row. That "8th column" would be out of bounds.

Comment: I tried changing the declared 7 into 8 but still got an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, specifically it states java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8

Comment: you would also have to use the modulus operator (%) to reset the column to 0 after each row

Comment: Oh ok, I'll use that modulus operator, but in which part of the code will I put it??

Comment: instead of read2DString[read2DStringIndex][g] = fromfile[g]; use read2DString[read2DStringIndex][g%7] = fromfile[g];

Comment: Ok I used this revision of yours:  read2DString[read2DStringIndex][g%7] = fromfile[g];
But it only worked for the first input, but on the second input, it resulted to java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Which the issue is still found on the same line of code:   read2DString[read2DStringIndex][g%7] = fromfile[g];

Comment: what was the second input? is it a different data set? if the dash is not in every 8th column, the program will yield an out of bounds error.

Comment: Yes, the second input contains different values compared to the first input.

Comment: you have to make sure the data is formatted in the exact way you described, namely, 7 columns of data followed by a dash. Is that true for the second data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before parsing your data into a 2D array, your code loops through a 1D array of the data, each eventual row separated by dashes. When you get to the for-loop, your code views the dash as an 8th column in the line  `read2DString[read2DStringIndex][g] = fromfile[g]`, as g would represent an index of 7. Only afterward does your code increment the row. To solve this, you would want to put the if-statement before this line and then use "continue;" to skip to the next iteration of the loop to bypass this problem.

You also have to reset the columns to 0 when you increment the row so instead of
`read2DString[read2DStringIndex][g] = fromfile[g]`
, use `read2DString[read2DStringIndex][g%8] = fromfile[g]`. The modulus operator (%) will give you the remainder after division, which in this case is the correct column number after dividing out the length of completed rows worth of columns.

Comment: Oh my!!! It worked, it didn't gave any out of bounds exception!!! Thank you very much @Moshe Goldberg!! I will be updating you when stuff comes up but again thank you very much!!
This was the revised structure just like I followed your concept:

Comment: String [][] read2DString = new String[10][8]; // changed this into 8

then..

 for(int g = 0; g < fromfile.length; g++){  
             if(fromfile[g].equals("-"))    
                  continue;
                 
             
            read2DString[read2DStringIndex][g%7] = fromfile[g];

Comment: if you make it 8 (instead of 7) as you did, you will end up with an empty 8th column. This won't cause errors, but it shouldn't be necessary if you move up the if-statement and use the continue statement.

Comment: ohh ok ok, so I'll just stick it to 7??

Comment: yes. although come to think of it, the modulus should be of 8, not 7 (g%8) because every new row starts after the dash (new row starts after 8 items)

Comment: correct me if im wrong. print out the 2d array to see if it works

Comment: ok, I'll try it, I'll give updates once I run it

Comment: helloo, I runned it, it only prints null values when I implemented the 2d array's columns to 7 and used (g%8)

Comment: are you sure you're printing it correctly? did it work before this most recent setup?

Comment: keep in mind, in your first dataset, a lot of the values seem to be null

Comment: I print the values using for loops:

for(int h = 0; h < read2DString.length; h++){  //prints read2DString
            for(int p = 0; p < read2DString[0].length; p++){
                System.out.println(read2DString[h][p] + ",");
            }
        }

Comment: also, should I not use anymore the read2DStringIndex++; (which increments the row of the 2D array)?

Comment: why should you take it out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230261/discussion-between-moshe-goldberg-and-ralph-henry).